# How to manage the risk of race conditions in useEffects when a component can un-mount at any time, with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Using TypeScript 4, React 17 (current versions at the time I'm writing these lines).

Let say I have the following component.

This component is behind a React Navigation conditional stack navigator. This mean that if the user un-connect, the component will be automatically unmounted and the with the whole UI, showing the login screen instead.

This is managed by such code in the app's root navigator:

```
user ? (
    <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
) : (
    <RootStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
)
```

Here is a component that print on the home screen.

I had some issues in another project and a friend of mine recommended to always put this un-mounting condition when a component un-mount with a risk of race condition.

I have some race conditions issues but adding un-mounting on all the components did not solved it so far.

Is my friend right that I shall continue to put these un-mounting or is it un-needed for such simple and synchronous cases as the following component?

```
interface Props {
    prop1: number
}

const MyFunctionalComponent: FC<Props> = ({prop1 = 0}: Props) => {

    const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState<string>('initial value')

    useEffect(() => {
        let mounted = true
        if (mounted) {
          // We are synchronous, no await there.
          const newStateVariable: string = stringify(prop1)
          setStateVariable(newStateVariable)
        }
        return (): void => {
          mounted = false
        }
    }, [prop1])

    return <Text>{ stateVariable }</Text>
}
```

What do you use and know about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `useEffect` hook's clean up to do this.

`useEffect` hook is run when dependency list is changed. Which is like `componentDidUpdate` in the `React` class components.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // This runs every time the prop1 changes

 return () => {
  // This runs every time the prop1 changes
 };
}, [prop1]);
```

If you just have empty array for dependency list then it works like `componentDidMount` in the `React` class components.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // This runs when component mounts
   // see there is no dependency passed for this

 return () => {
  // This runs when component un mounts
  // Do your cleanup here as it is run only on unmount
 };
}, []);
```

`useEffect` hook runs all the when its own `state` or `props` change if neither empty array or dependency list is passed.

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Runs every time the component renders

});
```

I guess now it is now clear about your case.

You don't have to use the `mounted` variable itself. Every time when your `prop1` changes the `stateVariable` will get updated.

```
const MyFunctionalComponent: FC<Props> = ({prop1 = 0}: Props) => {

    const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState<string>('initial value')

    useEffect(() => {
       // We are synchronous, no await there.
       const newStateVariable: string = stringify(prop1)

       setStateVariable(newStateVariable)
    }, [prop1])

    return <Text>{ stateVariable }</Text>
}
```

Some of the cases when you need to use the `cleanup` function

1. To `removeEventListener` on `document` or `window` or any other subscription that functional component has made.
2. To dispatch to cleanup store(if needed) if you are using redux.
3. To `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout` if there are any.

Some of the cases where not use the `cleanup` function

1. To set the state of the functional component that is un mounting.
2. In the case like your question (not needed at all).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `MyFunctionalComponent`, you should call [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) instead of `useState()` and `useEffect()`:

```
interface Props {
    prop1: number
}

const MyFunctionalComponent: FC<Props> = ({ prop1 = 0 }: Props) => {
    const computedVariable = useMemo(() => {
        return stringify(prop1)
    }, [prop1])

    return <Text>{ computedVariable }</Text>
}
```

`useState()` should only be necessary if you need a stateful value. In the example you provided, `stateVariable` is purely dependent on `prop1`, without any delay, so it doesn't actually need to be stateful at all. `useMemo()` is technically also a stateful hook, but is only there to avoid unnecessary repetition of expensive computations when the inputs are unchanged.